# psql error when used with username containing at (@) and using URL

Tags: psql

I'm trying to connect to my PostgreSQL 11.3 server using CLI (psql). I have a requirement to set password in command line (cannot use environment variable `PGPASSWORD`).
I'm trying to use an URL to access database like this:

```
psql postgresql://username@server:password@server.full.name:5432/db_name
```

As you see, my login contains at (`@`) in it, e.g. my login name is: `username@server`.

I get error:

```
psql: Invalid port number: "password@server.full.name:5432/db_name"
```

I suppose that psql CLI parses first at (`@`) as a delimiter between username and server name. Is is a psql CLI bug?

How can I pass such username (containing `@`) in URL to start psql properly?

Thanks!

**Update 1:**

My colleague suggested to use `%40` instead of colon `:` between login and password like this:

```
psql postgresql://username@server%40password@server.full.name:5432/db_name
```

But this has no effect (I use Windows 10, cmd.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigation, I found a solution (for the benefit of others):

```
psql postgresql://username%40server:password@server.full.name:5432/db_name
```

If you start it from `cmd` or `bat` file, mask percent sign (`%`) like this:

```
psql postgresql://username%%40server:password@server.full.name:5432/db_name
```